# How can I call a function that takes 2 parameters with a Tuple2?

Tags: scala, tuples

I have a function like so:

```
def print(name:String, surname:String) { println(name + " " + surname) }
```

I also have a Tuple2:

```
val johnsmith = ("John", "Smith")
```

When I call print with johnsmith I get the following error:

```
scala> print(johnsmith)                                                       

error: not enough arguments for method print: (name: String,surname: String)Unit.
Unspecified value parameter surname.
       print(johnsmith)
            ^
```

Is there some way around this? I can get this to work by making print accept a Tuple2:

```
def print2(t:Tuple2[String,String]) { println(t._1 + " " + t._2) }
```

Now I can call it either way:

```
scala> print2(johnsmith)
John Smith

scala> print2("john", "smith")
john smith
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First convert the method to a function, and then convert the function of two args into a function of one tuple.

```
Function.tupled(print _)(johnsmith)
```

Answer (score 10):

In addition to [Dave's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372283/dave-griffith) answer, this works too:

```
(print _).tupled(johnsmith)
```

Usually, Function.tupled will work best for anonymous functions and closures in combination with `map` and similar methods. For example:

```
List("abc", "def", "ghi").zipWithIndex.map(Function.tupled(_ * _))
```

In this case, the type for `_ * _` is already defined by `Function.tupled`. Try using `tupled` for that instead and it won't work, because the function is defined before `tupled` converts it.

For your particular case, `tupled` works, since the type of `print` is already known.